# How to override buid id,vendor name details in selenium firefox profile - Python

Tags: python-2.7, firefox, selenium

I need to override few details like app version,buld id, vendor name  in selenium Firefox profile to avoid browser finger printing.I tried the below code but that is not working, can some one please help me to fix this issue.Firefox version : 38.6.1 , Selenium :2.52, OS : mac

```
# coding=utf-8
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8-*-
from selenium import webdriver
import json
import os
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile

firefoxProfile = FirefoxProfile()
firefoxProfile.set_preference('general.platform.override','test_platform_info')
firefoxProfile.set_preference('general.appversion.override','test_app_version_in')
firefoxProfile.set_preference("general.productSub.override", 'test_sub')
firefoxProfile.set_preference("general.buildID.override", 'test_build_info')
firefoxProfile.set_preference('general.useragent.vendor', 'bla')
firefoxProfile.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefoxProfile)
driver.get("https://www.browserleaks.com/javascript#further-reading")
```

Expected Result:

```
Build ID : test_build_info
Product Sub : test_sub
Vendor : bla
```

Current Result :

```
Build ID : xxxxxxx
Product Sub : xxxxxx
Vendor : empty
```